# How to use supercluster

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am new to mapbox.
I need to use [the supercluster project of mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster) in order to plot 6 millions of gps in a map.
i tried to use [the demo](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/tree/master/demo) in localhost but i only get an empty map  !?

this is my code in **index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Supercluster Leaflet demo</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cluster.css" />

        <style>
            html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
         <script src="index.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/supercluster@3.0.2/dist/supercluster.min.js">

    var index = supercluster({
      radius: 40,
      maxZoom: 16
     });
       index.load(GeoObs.features);
       index.getClusters([-180, -85, 180, 85], 2);
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note** : *GeoObs* is my **geojson** file

what is wrong ?

Comment: Where do you initialise the map and add layers to it?

Comment: in index.js =>[index.js](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/blob/master/demo/index.js)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I Solved my issue.

to use the supercluster project you need :

1) download and install : [**node and npm**](https://nodejs.org/en/)

2) with npm install supercluster: `npm i supercluster`

then you will get a folder named *node_modules* in which you will find *supercluster folder* under it copy the folder named *dist* (node_modules>supercluster>dist)

3) download from github [**the project supercluster**](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster) here you will get a folder named *supercluster-master* **past** in it the folder **dist** copied in step 2)

- Now you can test it by selecting **index.html** into your browser (supercluster-master>demo>index.html)
- if you want to test another JSON or GEOJSON file just:

*1*) put this file under fixtures folder
   (supercluster-master>test>fixtures)

then

*2*) open worker.js (supercluster-master>demo>worker.js) and change the first variable of the geojson function to point on that file

example :

`getJSON('../test/fixtures/myFile.geojson', function (geojson) {`

## **Alternatively**

you can use the super-cluster algorithme directley in *mapbox gl js* [**mapBox gl js example**](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/) or with jupyter version;mapbox-jupyter [**mapbox-jupyter example**](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mapbox/mapboxgl-jupyter/blob/master/examples/notebooks/point-viz-types-example.ipynb#Create-a-clustered-circle-map)

Answer (score 8):

FWIW here is a self-contained example of how to use [supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster), without a Web Worker. It is also simply based on the repo demo.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 0);

// Empty Layer Group that will receive the clusters data on the fly.
var markers = L.geoJSON(null, {
  pointToLayer: createClusterIcon
}).addTo(map);

// Update the displayed clusters after user pan / zoom.
map.on('moveend', update);

function update() {
  if (!ready) return;
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var bbox = [bounds.getWest(), bounds.getSouth(), bounds.getEast(), bounds.getNorth()];
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  var clusters = index.getClusters(bbox, zoom);
  markers.clearLayers();
  markers.addData(clusters);
}

// Zoom to expand the cluster clicked by user.
markers.on('click', function(e) {
  var clusterId = e.layer.feature.properties.cluster_id;
  var center = e.latlng;
  var expansionZoom;
  if (clusterId) {
    expansionZoom = index.getClusterExpansionZoom(clusterId);
    map.flyTo(center, expansionZoom);
  }
});

// Retrieve Points data.
var placesUrl = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/mapbox/supercluster/v4.0.1/test/fixtures/places.json';
var index;
var ready = false;

jQuery.getJSON(placesUrl, function(geojson) {
  // Initialize the supercluster index.
  index = supercluster({
    radius: 60,
    extent: 256,
    maxZoom: 18
  }).load(geojson.features); // Expects an array of Features.

  ready = true;
  update();
});

function createClusterIcon(feature, latlng) {
  if (!feature.properties.cluster) return L.marker(latlng);

  var count = feature.properties.point_count;
  var size =
    count < 100 ? 'small' :
    count < 1000 ? 'medium' : 'large';
  var icon = L.divIcon({
    html: '<div><span>' + feature.properties.point_count_abbreviated + '</span></div>',
    className: 'marker-cluster marker-cluster-' + size,
    iconSize: L.point(40, 40)
  });

  return L.marker(latlng, {
    icon: icon
  });
}

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mapbox/supercluster/v4.0.1/demo/cluster.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/supercluster@4.0.1/dist/supercluster.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

Comment: hey @ghybs  did you know  how to use supercluster on server-side using node.js ?

Comment: Very probably the same as in a browser, only the querying would be different, but that is not the scope of the plugin. If you need help, feel free to ask a new question with specific details.

Comment: i just asked  [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304935/supercluster-on-server-side)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 0);

// Empty Layer Group that will receive the clusters data on the fly.
var markers = L.geoJSON(null, {
  pointToLayer: createClusterIcon
}).addTo(map);

// Update the displayed clusters after user pan / zoom.
map.on('moveend', update);

function update() {
  if (!ready) return;
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var bbox = [bounds.getWest(), bounds.getSouth(), bounds.getEast(), bounds.getNorth()];
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  var clusters = index.getClusters(bbox, zoom);
  markers.clearLayers();
  markers.addData(clusters);
}

// Zoom to expand the cluster clicked by user.
markers.on('click', function(e) {
  var clusterId = e.layer.feature.properties.cluster_id;
  var center = e.latlng;
  var expansionZoom;
  if (clusterId) {
    expansionZoom = index.getClusterExpansionZoom(clusterId);
    map.flyTo(center, expansionZoom);
  }
});

// Retrieve Points data.
var placesUrl = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/mapbox/supercluster/v4.0.1/test/fixtures/places.json';
var index;
var ready = false;

jQuery.getJSON(placesUrl, function(geojson) {
  // Initialize the supercluster index.
  index = supercluster({
    radius: 60,
    extent: 256,
    maxZoom: 18
  }).load(geojson.features); // Expects an array of Features.

  ready = true;
  update();
});

function createClusterIcon(feature, latlng) {
  if (!feature.properties.cluster) return L.marker(latlng);

  var count = feature.properties.point_count;
  var size =
    count < 100 ? 'small' :
    count < 1000 ? 'medium' : 'large';
  var icon = L.divIcon({
    html: '<div><span>' + feature.properties.point_count_abbreviated + '</span></div>',
    className: 'marker-cluster marker-cluster-' + size,
    iconSize: L.point(40, 40)
  });

  return L.marker(latlng, {
    icon: icon
  });
}

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mapbox/supercluster/v4.0.1/demo/cluster.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/supercluster@4.0.1/dist/supercluster.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 0);

// Empty Layer Group that will receive the clusters data on the fly.
var markers = L.geoJSON(null, {
  pointToLayer: createClusterIcon
}).addTo(map);

// Update the displayed clusters after user pan / zoom.
map.on('moveend', update);

function update() {
  if (!ready) return;
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var bbox = [bounds.getWest(), bounds.getSouth(), bounds.getEast(), bounds.getNorth()];
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  var clusters = index.getClusters(bbox, zoom);
  markers.clearLayers();
  markers.addData(clusters);
}

// Zoom to expand the cluster clicked by user.
markers.on('click', function(e) {
  var clusterId = e.layer.feature.properties.cluster_id;
  var center = e.latlng;
  var expansionZoom;
  if (clusterId) {
    expansionZoom = index.getClusterExpansionZoom(clusterId);
    map.flyTo(center, expansionZoom);
  }
});

// Retrieve Points data.
var placesUrl = 'https://dev.infrapedia.com/api/assets/map/facilities.points.json';
var index;
var ready = false;

jQuery.getJSON(placesUrl, function(geojson) {
  // Initialize the supercluster index.
  index = supercluster({
    radius: 60,
    extent: 256,
    maxZoom: 18
  }).load(geojson.features); // Expects an array of Features.

  ready = true;
  update();
});

function createClusterIcon(feature, latlng) {
  if (!feature.properties.cluster) return L.marker(latlng);

  var count = feature.properties.point_count;
  var size =
    count < 100 ? 'small' :
    count < 1000 ? 'medium' : 'large';
  var icon = L.divIcon({
    html: '<div><span>' + feature.properties.point_count_abbreviated + '</span></div>',
    className: 'marker-cluster marker-cluster-' + size,
    iconSize: L.point(40, 40)
  });

  return L.marker(latlng, {
    icon: icon
  });
}

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mapbox/supercluster/v4.0.1/demo/cluster.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/supercluster@4.0.1/dist/supercluster.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```