# SuperCluster On Server-Side

Tags: node.js, leaflet

While trying to visualize **2 million** of markers using the [SuperCluster project](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster) , i get this error :

```
 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/supercluster-master/supercluster-master/test/fixtures/taxi2.geojson. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

the  Owner of the project told me [here](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/issues/95) that is an *XMLHttpRequest* Problem and to Solve it i need to **serve my page with static server**.

So ,*since i didn't study node.js before*,I searched how node.js projects are used in server.

what i find is that the node.js project needs to contain **server.js** file which is missed in [SuperCluster project](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster).

I am asking how is it possible  to Serve this project ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209958/is-my-geojson-data-file-created-correclty/36217898#36217898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,

just install **http-server** and **node-static** (description [here](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255)), then put your supercluster project on **fixtures** *(node-static/test/fixtures)*.

after that run :

```
node-static> http-server -p 8000
```

and point your browser to :
    http://localhost:8000/test/fixtures/supercluster-master/demo/

Comment: I need your help to integrate this server side super cluster. Please help me

Comment: I need to do server side clustering in Node js. If you know any other details please share with me

Comment: all what i know is described in the solution ,  i used superCluster for a reasearch project not for developpment, you can ask a new question describing your problem in details.
ghybs can help you